# overriding css styles with @import not working

Tags: css, import, overriding

I'v seen some similar questions about overriding styles with @import, people suggest to put @import at the bottom, but that does not seem to work here.

```
--- index.html ---
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
This text should be green.
</body>

--- style.css ---
body {color: red;}
@import url('style-override.css');

--- style-override.css ---
body {color: green;}
```

The example above will output **red** text, while **green** is expected.

- Declaring style-override.css after style.css inside head will solve the problem, but I want to use @import **inside** a css file.
- Adding **!important** in style-override.css will also get the expected result, but that is not the way it should work.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That isn't working because any import rule declared inside of a stylesheet must come before everything else - otherwise, ...well, it doesn't work ;) .

So, what you should have in your style.css stylesheet is:

```
@import url('style-override.css');  
body {color: red;}
```

Comment: OK, even if @import is declared at the bottom, it will be executed first I guess. I actually just read that on a website. It seems that declaring css inside head or adding !important are the only ways. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes, obviously. I wasn't even thinking about that. The imported rules are still overridden, since, in this case `body {color: red;}` comes after.

Answer (score 26):

`@import` rules must be at the *top*. This is what the [CSS spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-cascade-3-20131003/#at-import) says about it:

> Any @import rules must precede all other at-rules and style rules in a style sheet (besides @charset, which must be the first thing in the style sheet if it exists), or else the @import rule is invalid.